# Weird 403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /< on this server

Tags: php, html, wamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [All localhost pages via WAMP blocked??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296007/all-localhost-pages-via-wamp-blocked)

I'm running WAMP on localhost and am trying to use a modal window to submit something to my database.

When I had the form to submit outside of the modal window to appear on the page itself, no problems.

When I try to submit from the modal window, I get the following error (403 Forbidden):

**Forbidden**

You don't have permission to access /< on this server.

Any ideas? 
I'm not sure what to try next.

EDIT: This is NOT a duplicate. My other question arose in the process of trying to fix this.

EDIT2: I used GET instead of POST to see if I can narrow down this problem. Here's what comes into my address bar when I get this error:

```
http://localhost/%3C?php%20echo%20$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];%20?%3E
```

And here's the code in that php file (that's associated with the modal window)

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<label> <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />Who?: <br />
<textarea name="nametext" rows="1" cols="10"></textarea></label>
<select name="ident" id="ident">
        <option value="yankees">Yankees</option>
        <option value="phillies">Phillies</option>
        <option value="announcer">Announcer</option>
</select>
<label> <br />What did they say?: <br />
<textarea name="quotetext" rows="10" cols="26"></textarea></label>
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
<br />
</form>
<a href="#" class="lbAction" rel="deactivate">Close Lightbox.</a>
```

Comment: The phpMyAdmin modal window? I think this might be a server configuration issue not PHP itself.

Comment: 'You don't have permission to access /< on this server.' It appears you are requesting a file called '<' which I'm guessing isn't there?

Comment: @GolezTrol: It's in javascript as well. @seacode: any insight on what i might need to change?

Comment: Is this different from your other question?  If not, you should delete it.  If it is, you should clarify.

Comment: @jeff @sixletter: No, this is not a duplicate. That other question arose as a result of trying to fix this.

Comment: @Tony what i meant was you seemed to have solved your other question.  Does that solution fix this problem as well?

Comment: @Jeff No, this problem still stands.

Comment: @Tory take a look at this: http://www.wampserver.com/phorum/read.php?2,44414,44416  This user got the same error because he/she started his php tag with <? instead of <?php

Comment: @Jeff: Yeah, I've googled this to no end and found that that was the solution to a lot of these problems. I've checked my code and can't seem to find an error like that. Just in case, I've enabled short tags in phpMyAdmin. Same error still.

Comment: Is the file containing that code named in such a way that it will be interpreted as PHP?

Comment: Ah-ha, code snippets, now we're getting somewhere =] I assume your file ends in .php?

Comment: @Jack @Jeff: Yes, it is a .php file.

Comment: @Tory the post was closed because it looked identical to your other post, pre-edits.  If you're still having trouble, I suggest reposting with a title like 'Why isn't WAMP parsing my PHP files?', and make sure to post some of your code and perhaps any relevant info from your httpd config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here's what comes into my address bar when I get this error:

```
http://localhost/%3C?php%20echo%20$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];%20?%3E
```

Then your PHP is not getting parsed. Your HTML form contains the raw PHP code as its destination, so of *course* you're getting access failure — a few factors may be contributing to your getting 403, not 404.

Fix your server config to make PHP work.